# Broken SSH sudo - parse error in /etc/sudoers

Tags: debian, ssh, sudo, root

Today I run into ironic and awful situation - I have broken sudo command. I don't have physical connection to the machine. The only way I can access server is via SSH.

So firstly I connected as "client_user" to server via ssh and then switched to root with sudo su root.
I used vim command for editing /etc/sudoers and took down "#" character from include line. That gave me syntax error.

The worst part is that I don't have root user password.
I have google for over 4 hours and have tried:

- mv & cp sudoers, but for that I need sudo rights
- pkexec visudo but it's not available on debian or simply just not installed. To install apps we need sudo.
- pktyagent command with 2 different sessions
- su root command but it's not usable without password

People on the internet recommended to use recovery mode but as far as I am concerned it is not possible using SSH.

The only possible solution which caught my eye was to use root's active cron job to chown sudoers file. But not sure if that possible without sudo. Also heard about adding script to ,,Tasks Scheduler" for changing sudoers file.

Maybe somebody have any ideas?

Adding photo to make everything more clear.
[image]

Comment: I know this won't help you, but for future users (and future you): ***never edit `/etc/sudoers` directly! ALWAYS use `visudo`, that's what it's for.***

Comment: Yes, I deffinitely have learned my lesson now - to use visudo in the future. It checks syntax.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify that you do not have physical access to the machine and that the only way you have of accessing it is via `ssh`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: If anybody is scared of the name, `visudo` invokes `$EDITOR` (there are a couple of other environment variables that have influence, but if they are set, the user probably knows what he's doing) and not `vi`, so there's no reason not to *use `visudo`*!

Comment: In general it's possible to create a syntactically valid `sudoers` file that will not grant you `sudo` access. So *aside* from using `visudo` you should keep an additional root shell open. Exit this emergency shell only after you confirm you can use `sudo` (especially `sudo visudo`) after the changes. In case the connection breaks it's good to have this emergency shell inside `tmux` (or `screen`) which runs for your regular user, so you can reconnect as the regular user, reattach to `tmux` and the emergency shell is still there. Such shell can be a life-saver.

Comment: "_I connected as root to server via ssh_" do you really mean you were able to login directly as root? If so there's no problem

Comment: I connected as user named "client_user", then used "sudo su root". If I am correct it asked for client_user password or no password at all. But now I can't use "sudo". After broken sudo I have tried just changing user with "su root", but it asks for root password without sudo. So looks like there is no way to swap to root user (without knowing password atleast) or use sudo without fixing sudoers file.